# Django URL not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've a url in my urls.py as follow:-

```
url(r'^api/profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.ProfileDetail.as_view()),
```

My username is same as my emailid ,ie `something@gmail.com`. When I browse to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/something@gmail.com/`, it says `404 Page not found`.

If username is changed to normal word (not like emailid), the url works fine. How do I make sure that url takes emailids as the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the match url regex:

```
 url(r'^api/profile/(?P<username>[@\.\w]+)/$', views.ProfileDetail.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match all of the characters that are in an email address. The `\w` matches the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and underscore. Email addresses include @ and ., neither of which are matched.

You'll need to change your regex to match a valid email address. Django has some built-in email address regexes, but they're extremely complex. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#151 if you want to see what they're like.

For your purposes, it's likely that something like the following will suffice:

```
url(r'^api/profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9\+@\._-]+)/$', views.ProfileDetail.as_view()),
```

Comment: You have to escape `.` and `+` in you regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9\+@\._-]`